# Activity Indicator in Swift

Tags: ios, function, swift, uiactivityindicatorview

I am trying to make activity indicator using swift but there is something I am missing

Here is the code for start activity button button:

```
Indicator = ActivityIndicator().StartActivityIndicator(ViewController());
```

And here is the code for stop activity button

```
 ActivityIndicator().StopActivityIndicator(ViewController(),indicator: Indicator);
```

and code for ACtivity indicator class is

```
class ActivityIndicator: NSObject {

    var myActivityIndicator:UIActivityIndicatorView!

    func StartActivityIndicator(obj:UIViewController) -> UIActivityIndicatorView
    {

        self.myActivityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100)) as UIActivityIndicatorView;

        self.myActivityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.Gray
        self.myActivityIndicator.center = obj.view.center;

        obj.view.addSubview(myActivityIndicator);

        self.myActivityIndicator.startAnimating();
        return self.myActivityIndicator;
    }

    func StopActivityIndicator(obj:UIViewController,indicator:UIActivityIndicatorView)-> Void
    {
            indicator.removeFromSuperview();
    }


}
```

> **Thanks Problem Solved**
>
> while am writing code I know that time that I have to pass self in the
>   function but at that time I didn't know What type is self referencing
>   so I I can't receive until I know the type then I decide to try to
>   receive different type (UIView,
>   UIActivityIndicatorView,UIViewController) then I found That it should
>   be UIViewController but I forgot that it should be pass with self and
>   I looking for what to pass in function calling and I thought let's try
>   UIViewController and it didn't give me error so I thought it's right
>   but when it's not working I thought I am close enough so it's better
>   to ask expert about the problem. And as I expected problem is solved
>   within few minutes

Swift 3 version

```
class ActivityIndicator: NSObject {

    var myActivityIndicator:UIActivityIndicatorView!

    func StartActivityIndicator(obj:UIViewController) -> UIActivityIndicatorView
    {

        self.myActivityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame:CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100)) as UIActivityIndicatorView

        self.myActivityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.gray
        self.myActivityIndicator.center = obj.view.center;

        obj.view.addSubview(myActivityIndicator);

        self.myActivityIndicator.startAnimating();
        return self.myActivityIndicator;
    }

    func StopActivityIndicator(obj:UIViewController,indicator:UIActivityIndicatorView)-> Void
    {
        indicator.removeFromSuperview();
    }


}
```

Comment: When you call `StopActivityIndicator()` (which should start with a Lowe case s, by the way) you are calling it on a new instance instead of the instance that was returned by the start function

Comment: No its Upper case s  and I am calling it right but if this the case then there should be problem in stoping the indicator not starting right ?

Comment: The upper/lower case s is just convention - classes start with a capital, functions and variables start with a lower case letter. The problem is you are stopping a new instance rather that the instance you started. You need to save the object from the start call and call stop on that instance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seem that every time you call start/stop,you create a new instance of `ViewController`
Just replace `ViewController` to `self` and try

For example

```
Indicator = ActivityIndicator().StartActivityIndicator(self);
```

Comment: @VarunNaharia By using `ViewController()` you are creating a new instance of the `ViewController` class, and that instance is not being shown unless you explicitly present it. Using `self` refers to the instance of the controller that is calling the method, and since it *is* being shown, you will see your indicator.